# How to use certain curl in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, cmd

I have tried using curl-to-ruby (https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/)

```
uri = URI.parse("https://api.wappalyzer.com/lookup/v1/?url=https://example.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["X-Api-Key"] = "wappalyzer.api.demo.key"
req_options = {  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https", }
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

Had no success, it gives back a http response code.

This is my curl:

```
curl -H "X-Api-Key: wappalyzer.api.demo.key" https://api.wappalyzer.com/lookup/v1/?url=https://example.com&callback_url=https://theverge.com
```

It's supposed to give back data about in what a website is made.

example of what its supposed to give:

```
[{"monthYear":"12-2019","languages":[],"applications":[{"name":"Apache","categories":["Web Servers"],"versions":["2.4.29"],"hits":754},{"name":"Ubuntu","categories":["Operating Systems"],"versions":[],"hits":754},{"name":"PHP","categories":["Programming Languages"],"versions":[],"hits":713},{"name":"Symfony",
```

Comment: Paste converted ruby code in irb console and check `response.body`
Also, add error that you are facing

Comment: make sure you have these two lines
`require 'net/http'`
`require 'uri'`

Comment: If you want to actually use curl you can use `curb` gem https://rubygems.org/gems/curb/versions/0.9.10

Comment: @arieljuod but why use curb if std-lib net/http works ?

Comment: @ChrisServ so why are you using the curl converter if it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @lacostenycoder it's just another option, someone may want to use curl and there's a gem for that and that's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work but you need to look at `response.body`:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.wappalyzer.com/lookup/v1/?url=https://example.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["X-Api-Key"] = "wappalyzer.api.demo.key"
req_options = {  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https" }
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

puts response.body
```